# Properties of join of open covers

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am studying the basics on Ergodic Theory from Fundamentos da Teoria Ergodica by Oliveira & Viana (you can actually find the pdf on their website), particularly, the properties of topological pressure. I got a bit confused by some remarks on the join of partitions.

Let $f:M\to M$ continuous on a compact metric space $M$. If $\alpha$ es an open cover of $M$, then $f^{-j}(\alpha)$ is also an open cover for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Define $\alpha^n$ by

$$ \alpha^n:=\bigvee_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{-i}(\alpha)=\{P_0\cap...\cap P_n : P_i\in f^{-j}(\alpha)\}$$

At page 301, it s remarked that $(\alpha^k)^n=\alpha^{n+k}$. But then at page 302, it is remarked that $(\alpha^k)^n=\alpha^{kn}$. I got really confused, so I tried to prove by myself.

I could see that $f^{-1}(\bigvee_{i}P_i)=\bigvee f^{-1}(P_i)$, so by iterating you get that

\begin{align*}
(\alpha^k)^n&=\left( \bigvee_{j=0}^{k-1}f^{-j}(\alpha)\right)^n \\
&=\bigvee_{l=0}^{n-1}f^{-l}\left(\bigvee_{j=0}^{k-1}f^{-j}(\alpha) \right)\\
&=\bigvee_{l=0}^{n-1}\bigvee_{j=0}^{k-1}f^{-(j+l)}(\alpha)
\end{align*}

and I don't know how to get $(\alpha)^{kn}$ or $(\alpha)^{n+k}$ from that.

Edit

The context I'm working is proving the following properties of topological pressure: $P(f,\phi,\alpha^k)=P(f,\phi,\alpha)$ and $P(f^k,\phi_k)=k P(f,\phi)$ with the open cover definition of pressure. Is there any way to prove it without using those remarks? (Using the open cover definition of pressure, not the $(n,\epsilon)$ definition used by Walters).

Comment: That's a statement about partitions. On pages 329 and 330 you can see the statements on open covers. Even though, I think it's weird, open covers and partitions share some properties, so I think they should behave similarly.

Comment: in your definition of $\alpha^n$ do you mean $P_i \inf^{-j}(\alpha) $ or $P_i \inf^{-i}(\alpha)$?

Comment: @FelipePérez My bad, thanks for pointing that out. I believe the claim $\beta^n = \alpha^{kn}$ where $\beta = \alpha^k$ uses $f^k$ instead of $f$ as the continuous transformation to obtain the exponents of $\beta$, i.e. $\beta^n := \bigvee_{i=0}^{n-1} (f^k)^{-i}(\beta)$, because immediately afterwards we calculate $P_n(f^k, \phi_k, \beta)$. I still need to think a bit about the first claim.

Comment: Oh, that's a really good point, @epimorphic. Thanks! I'll work on it.